# Is writing tablet like Wacom, Huion, Veikk and etc necessary for people who just want to write notes and Mathematical solutions in screen sharing?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is it advisable for people who are not interested in drawings, but buying for the purpose to share notes and writing Maths workout for discussion.
Will the speed of writing as fast as the speed of normal writing on papers?
Is there other cheaper options for people who see that buying a writing table just to write and share Maths steps online is a waste of money, especially to be used just during Covid-19 lockdown ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary by any means. Its rather nice to have in a few cases, but i will stress out a few.

I have a Large intuous pro attached to this computer i hardly ever use it, the only reason i have a intuous is so I can do sculpting, and painting. For typesetting equations there are way better systems. At work i have a cintix on my secondary desktop, hardly ever use it. I have access to surface pros that work fine as tablets again hardly ever use the pen for anything. Again it depends on workflow, but to be honest doing math typesetting is faster with keyboard and if needed mouse since my hand is already on it.

It is really important to understand that unless you spend time to build your workflow around the tablet it will not automatically make a you happy. To be honest spend the money on a license of Mathematica instead. So dont buy a tablet without testing one first.

[image]

**Image 1**: Test image took 30 seconds to with mouse 26 to do with mouse and 30 seconds to do with Tex. Considering switching form mouse to pen took 10 seconds seems like a waste of time

*NOTE*: I did not mention drawing with a tablet simply becasue i almost never do so. I only use a tablet if i need to color stuff as then its better than a mouse system.

Comment: The same here. I have an Intuos pro on both computers and hardly use them.